# Writing into a file Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get user input into a text file on different lines. The user input is stored in a list then the list is appended. I realize you are not suppose to use quotes since that will act as your own input. How could I go about using the user input?

```
def userfile():
   text = []
   s1 = input("Enter sentence #1 ")
   s1 = input("Enter sentence #2 ")
   text.append(s1)

   userfile = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w")
   lines = ['s1\n', 's1\n']
   userfile.writelines(lines)
   userfile.close()

   newfile = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],"sample2.txt"), "r")
   print(newfile.read())

def main():
   #txtfile()
   userfile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Probably don't use `userfile` as both the name of a function and a variable. If the variable is inside the function, it's merely confusing; if it's outside, you are wrecking your own program.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is in  `userfile()`: you write both inputs into the same variable `s1`. And then you don't even use the text array you just created.

Try this:

```py
def userfile():
    text = []
    text.append(input("Enter sentence #1 "))
    text.append(input("Enter sentence #2 "))
    # ...
    userfile.writelines(text)
    # ...
```

Comment: This could also work, I've run into the problem of formating the output on seperate lines

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just modify your code to  `lines = [s1+'\n', s1+'\n']` if I Understand your problem.

Comment: I used this except it only takes the last user input I tried making another variable but does not work

Answer (score 0):

First your indentation is wrong, and you are using a variable named userfile within a function called `userfile()` which is confusing but doesn't really matter, finally you are overwriting your `s1` variable with the second input.
I also recommend using `with` when opening a file as that will automatically close the file when finished with it.

```
def userfile():
    text = []
    for i in range(1, 3):
        text.append(input("Enter sentence #{i} ".format(i)))
    
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "sample2.txt"), "w") as my_file:
        my_file.writelines(text)
   
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],"sample2.txt"), "r") as new_file:
        print(new_file.read())

def main():
    # txtfile()
    userfile()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also I used a loop for the user input which allows you to require as many inputs from the user as you want by only changing 1 number.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know that using with would automatically close the file

Comment: Yes it will. And be sure to mark the correct answer and/or upvote good answers. Thank you.